# How to play a video file in Blackberry

Tags: video, blackberry, blackberry-10, playback

I am New to BlackBerry Development. Now I want to play a video file in my Blackberry Application.Now the player will show like this,

[image]

Here is my code,

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
import bb.multimedia 1.0

Page {
    Container {

        Button {
            id: playButton
            text: "Play"
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
            onClicked: {

                if (!player.isPlaying) {
                    console.log("myPlayer.isPlaying = true");
                    player.play();
                } else {
                    console.log("myPlayer.isPlaying = false");
                    player.pause();
                }
            }
        }

        ForeignWindowControl {
            id: videoSurface
            windowId: "myVideoSurface"
            updatedProperties: WindowProperty.Size | 
                    WindowProperty.Position | WindowProperty.Visible
            visible: boundToWindow
            preferredWidth: 640
            preferredHeight: 480
        } 

        attachedObjects: [
            MediaPlayer {

                id: player
                property bool isPlaying: false

                sourceUrl: "asset:///Videos/instruction.mp4"
                videoOutput: VideoOutput.PrimaryDisplay
                windowId: videoSurface.windowId 

                onMediaStateChanged: {
                    if (player.mediaState == MediaState.Started) {
                        console.log("player Started");

                        playButton.text = "Pause"
                        isPlaying = true;

                    } else if (player.mediaState == MediaState.Paused) {
                        console.log("player Paused");

                        playButton.text = "Play"
                        isPlaying = false;

                    } else if (player.mediaState == MediaState.Stopped) {
                        console.log("player Stopped");

                        playButton.text = "Play"
                        isPlaying = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        ] //attachedObjects
    }
}
```

Now while tap on the play button it will display like the image

Comment: Have you checked out these http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11942/Buffer_and_play_streamed_media_740033_11.jsp and https://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/tkb/articleprintpage/tkb-id/java_dev@tkb/article-id/398.

They are most likely what you're looking for.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check it.

Comment: What happens when you run the code?

Comment: @donturner The player will display as the image. And No video is played.